# QGIS - toggle between previously defined 'views'

Tags: qgis

I have a QGIS project that combines a number of background raster layers and vector layers showing a wide range of objects within my work site (tracks, culverts, felling progress layers, environmental constraints, aerial photos etc etc).

I would like to create a predefined 'view' of certain layers depending upon the task in hand and be able to toggle between views or select a view from a list to quickly switch to the assets relevent to the task.

I could create seperate projects with shared assets but that seems like a sledge hammer approach.
Is there plugin that allows this or should I learn python and create something :-)

Comment: Does map theme (https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html?highlight=theme#configuring-map-themes) is what you'r looking for ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please have a look at the [map themes](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html?highlight=map%20theme#configuring-map-themes). They should do what you're looking for. You can add any number of layers to a map theme, and when toggling that theme, all layers in it will be turned on, and all others turned off.